# How to call jar files in main

Tags: java, jar

I have many jar files around which does small little tasks on their own. I wish to create a main class with a menu and asking user to execute a task. How do I call the external jar file from main class? Using a system call ? I do not want to re-do all the jar files to combine them into one main program.

eg I have these jars, which does one particular task. These are already done long ago.

```
myPrintToPrinter.jar 
mySendEmail.jar
myCheckBuffer.jar
myAuditTrail.jar
```

I want to create a menu:

```
1) Print to printer
2) SEnd email
3) ....
```

and from user choice, I call each jar file. I believe i do need to shell out to call it?

thanks

Comment: You can use the [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)-class. Your command should be something like `java -jar your.jar`.

Comment: Are you talking about using the java classes in the jar files or starting a class containing a main method in on of the jar files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good approach would be to

```
1) create a folder with name lib
2) add all the required jar files there
3) Add the dependent jar files in the project (select from the lib folder,
   this is a good practice to keep the jars within the project folder to avoid path 
   dependencies when you move the project).
4) Create your required class and perform all the checks (logic part) in the main function.
```

you can even make the final jar by creating the RUNNABLE JAR of that created class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the URLClassLoader to load a JAR.
PFB a sample code how u can load a JAR from your Java code.
Hope this helps.

```
TestClass.java :
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    URLClassLoader loader = (URLClassLoader)ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();  
    MyClassLoader l = new MyClassLoader(loader.getURLs());  
    l.addURL(new URL("file:C:/work/mytestjar.jar")); 
    Class c = l.loadClass("com.test.MyJarClass"); // com.test.MyJarClass is the class from JAR
}

MyClassLoader.java:
public class MyClassLoader extends URLClassLoader
{  

    public MyClassLoader(URL[] urls) {  
        super(urls);  
    }  

    @Override  
    public void addURL(URL url) {  
        super.addURL(url);  
    }  
}
```

Comment: This is not a good approach, if you change the code in the depend jar files. you will have to change the given static paths as well..what if the code is used in a number of classes...

Comment: In this case u can keep the jar in projects lib folder

Comment: will have to change this location again and again if I move the project from one drive to another .. file:C:/work/mytestjar.jar